# Issue in R package Lavaan SEM modeling

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot

I want to create a Structural Equation Model (SEM) using the `lavaan` package in R. However, I am facing some issues during the modeling process. I am working with microbiome data. Could you please assist me in overcoming these problems?

I have used following codes for the analysis.

```
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)
m1b <-   '
  # regressions
    Dementia_AG ~ C_aerofaciens+C_stercoris-1
    Control_AG ~ O_formigenes+S_anginosus+C_perfringens+S_enterica-1
  # variance (optional)
    Dementia_AG ~~ Control_AG
'
fit1b <- sem(m1b, data=practice_data_for_SEM_analysis)
```

Warning messages:
1: In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive definite;
check your model and/or starting parameters.
2: In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive definite;
check your model and/or starting parameters.
3: In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive definite;
check your model and/or starting parameters.
4: In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive definite;
check your model and/or starting parameters.
5: In lavaan::lavaan(model = m1b, data = practice_data_for_SEM_analysis,  :
lavaan WARNING:
Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values.

```
cov(new_data)
```

```
          C_aerofaciens  C_stercoris  O_formigenes   S_anginosus C_perfringens
```

C_aerofaciens  1.245209e-03 2.544454e-05 -3.447328e-06 -8.998240e-07  2.428222e-06
C_stercoris    2.544454e-05 3.363217e-06  3.234814e-08  4.452791e-07  6.451469e-07
O_formigenes  -3.447328e-06 3.234814e-08  6.365657e-08  7.443029e-08  8.227743e-08
S_anginosus   -8.998240e-07 4.452791e-07  7.443029e-08  2.010881e-07  2.347277e-07
C_perfringens  2.428222e-06 6.451469e-07  8.227743e-08  2.347277e-07  3.409987e-07
S_enterica    -3.235251e-07 6.897520e-08  1.862812e-08  3.260950e-08  4.855493e-08
Dementia_AG    7.433954e-03 3.536726e-04  9.849102e-06  5.291080e-05  8.932950e-05
Control_AG    -2.998957e-03 1.523680e-04  5.693680e-05  9.224409e-05  1.157158e-04
S_enterica  Dementia_AG    Control_AG
C_aerofaciens -3.235251e-07 7.433954e-03 -2.998957e-03
C_stercoris    6.897520e-08 3.536726e-04  1.523680e-04
O_formigenes   1.862812e-08 9.849102e-06  5.693680e-05
S_anginosus    3.260950e-08 5.291080e-05  9.224409e-05
C_perfringens  4.855493e-08 8.932950e-05  1.157158e-04
S_enterica     1.356335e-08 1.488484e-05  1.527568e-05
Dementia_AG    1.488484e-05 7.811294e-02  1.023256e-02
Control_AG     1.527568e-05 1.023256e-02  7.015494e-02

Thank You
Rishikesh